# i have to export the data from database mysql to excel

Tags: laravel-5.8

```
when i am trying to export it says that the Export::create is not found class:

use DB;  
use Excel;  
class ExportExcelController extends Controller    
{  
  function index()  
  {                                 
    $customer_data=DB::table('book_details')->get();    
    return view('export_excel')->with('customer_data',$customer_data);  
  }

  function excel()
  {
    $customer_data=DB::table('book_details')->get()->toArray();
    $customer_array[]=array('ID','Book Name','Author Name','Publisher 
Name','Supplier Name','Department of book','Book status','Book Stock',
```

'Image');
          foreach($customer_data as $customer)
          {
            $customer_array[] = array('ID'=> $customer->id,
                'Book Name'=> $customer->book_name,
                'Author Name'=> $customer->book_author,
                'Publisher Name'=> $customer->book_publisher,
                'Supplier Name'=> $customer->book_supplier,
                'Department of book'=> $customer->book_dept,
                'Book status'=> $customer->book_status,
                'Book Stock'=> $customer->book_stock,
                'Image'=> $customer->book_image
             );
          }

```
    Excel::create('Book Data', function($excel) use($customer_array)
    {
        $excel->setTitle('Book Data');
        $excel->sheet('Book Data',function($sheet)
        use($customer_array)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray(
            $customer_array,null,'A1',false,false);
         });
     })->download('xlsx');
  }
```

Comment: please check whether the extension is installed correctly, check your composer.json. Please mention the package for more information

Comment: composer version is of 4.10 and php version is 7